# Get first value of year with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have the following table

|  | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 53 |
| 1/1/2023 | 54 |
| 1/1/2023 | 52 |
| 1/2/2023 | 55 |
| 1/2/2023 | 51 |
| 1/2/2023 | 52 |
| 1/2/2023 | 60 |
| 1/3/2023 | 41 |
| 1/3/2023 | 44 |

I created a dax formula which gives me the first value of 1/1/2023:

```
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Turn Over'[Effectif avant],'Turn Over'[Effectif avant]),
    MONTH('Turn Over'[Date])=1
)
```

The problem with this is that once I am in **2024** it will still take the first non blank value of 2023.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Turn Over'[Effectif avant],'Turn Over'[Effectif avant]),
    MONTH('Turn Over'[Date])=1 && YEAR('Turn Over'[Date])=2024
)
```

or dynamic:

```
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Turn Over'[Effectif avant],'Turn Over'[Effectif avant]),
    MONTH('Turn Over'[Date])=1 && YEAR('Turn Over'[Date])=YEAR(TODAY())
)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I like the dynamic way. But what about if I want to use slicers and check back the previous year? would I somehow have to use `SELECTEDVALUE()`?

Comment: Yes, you could use SELECTEDVALUE() with a slicer to get what you want. Don't forget to mark as solved and/or upvote